# How to see the result of ApexExecutionOverlayAction?

Tags: tooling-api

I can submit an ApexExecutionOverlayAction GET request using REST API and I get an ID in response. But how do I use the ID? How can I see the ApexExecutionOverlayResult for my ApexExecutionOverlayAction request?

I wish SFDC had better documentation for the Tooling API.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to execute the Apex Class/Trigger in question to hit the checkpoint. **You must have the Apex Code log level set to Finer or Finest.**

From [Setting Checkpoints in Apex Code](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_checkpoints_setting.htm&language=en_US):

> ### Important
>
> To use checkpoints, the Apex Log Level must be set to **Finer** or **Finest**. See [Setting Logging Levels](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_dev_console_tab_browser_logs.htm&language=en_US#set_log_levels).

---

## Retrieving the results:

There doesn't currently appear to be any direct queryable relationship between a [ApexExecutionOverlayResult](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexexecutionoverlayresult.htm) and the [ApexExecutionOverlayAction](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexexecutionoverlayaction.htm) that caused it.

You could probably use a combination of `Namespace`, `ClassName`, `Line` and `UserId` to retrieve a 
ApexExecutionOverlayResult for the associated ApexExecutionOverlayAction. Since you can only have one checkpoint per line this should return a unique result. Note that some of these fields don't appear in the online documentation, but you can query them.

Comment: I was looking at ways to get the ApexExecutionOverLayResult via Tooling API. I tried executing the Apex Class and then trying to query the ApexExecutionOverLayResult, but I didn't find a way to do it using the ApexExecutionOverLayRequest ID.

Answer (score 0):

The below is working for me using the workbench.

POST /services/data/v38.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexExecutionOverlayAction

```
{
"ActionScript" : "SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = '001[ACCOUNT-ID]'",
"ActionScriptType" : "SOQL",
"ExecutableEntityId" : "01p[CLASS_ID]",
"IsDumpingHeap" : "true",
"Iteration" : "1",
"Line" : "29",
"ScopeId" : "005[USER-ID]"
}
```

Or if you want to run Apex, it looks like this

```
{
"ActionScript" : "System.debug('Todd overlays'); System.debug([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = '001[ACCOUNT-ID]']);",
"ActionScriptType" : "Apex",
"ExecutableEntityId" : "01p[CLASS_ID]",
"IsDumpingHeap" : "true",
"Iteration" : "1",
"Line" : "29",
"ScopeId" : "005[USER-ID]"
}
```

That returns me an ID like 1doe00000000123 (not a real ID)  I will probably need that later.

But for now, I need the result ID.  Here's a basic query you can use:
GET /services/data/v38.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+ApexExecutionOverlayResult+ORDER+BY+CreatedDate+DESC+LIMIT+1

That gets me an ID such as 07ne00000001234 (not a real ID).  Then the details are available at
GET /services/data/v38.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexExecutionOverlayResult/07ne00000001234

When I do Apex rather than SOQL I wish I could get at instance variable values but it's not impossible to recreate them.

Two other notes.

1. If I don't specify an expiration date I get a default of 30 mins in the future
2. You can only have one Action for a give class and line.  So if you need to alter it, delete your old one with:
   DELETE /services/data/v38.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexExecutionOverlayAction/1doe00000000123